# How to vertically center an image Bootstrap card with fixed height

Tags: bootstrap-4

How can I vertically center an image in a fixed height bootstrap card?

I've tried playing with mx-auto and justify-content-center classes, but don't work.

Codeply: http://codeply.com/go/tXCgay8UDX

```
<div class="card mx-auto mb-2" style="width: 12rem;">
    <div class="" style="height:200px;">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="https://www.fillmurray.com/200/100" alt="Card image cap">
    </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <p class="card-text">Verticall center this image</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The image should be vertically entered in the card.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd make the image container display:flex using `d-flex` and then `align-items-center`...

```
<div class="card mx-auto mb-2" style="width: 12rem;">
    <div class="d-flex align-items-center" style="height:200px;">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="https://www.fillmurray.com/200/100" alt="Card image cap">
    </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <p class="card-text">Verticall center this image</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/ZVK6JIaECD

Answer (score -3):

You can use style="text-align:center"